# Sync a file geodatabase from a portable hard drive to mother database on my main computer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, data-backup

I have several file geodatabases to which I routinely add new data generated in the field.  To accommodate the mobile nature of this data creation and maintenance, I am working off of an external hard drive.  I would like the "mother" files of these geodatabases to live on my desktop, where I have a regular backup scheduled.  Is there a way I can set up a system to sync the updated geodatabases with this main GIS machine when I am back at the office?  I am unable to remotely access this main machine due to government restrictions.

I am running ArcGIS 10.2.2 with the ArcInfo license.

P.S. I am a new user and this is my first post, so I apologize if I'm missing anything or using poor form.

Comment: Look into [geodatabase replication](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Understanding_distributed_data/003n000000ts000000/)

Comment: Geodatabase replication is what you're looking for, but in order to use it you'll need to migrate to an RDMS from your current file geodatabase solution. PostgreSQL + ArcSDE would be a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively try geogig which uses the same concept.  as git or subversion to version control your data. You can add,commit and also have a history of what was done on a particular day. Just search boundless geogig